# How is the druid's Timeless Body feature helpful?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, aging

What effects, if any, interact with the druid's Timeless Body class feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion-based because how and when it comes into play is likely going to be different for each DM/game and there's no way to determine which answer is the "best".

Comment: I think the problem is phrasing. Consider something like *What effects, if any, interact with the druid's timeless body class feature?* or *How can I use the druid's timeless body class feature to my advantage during a campaign?* to make this question generate more specific answers.

Answer (score 16):

Timeless Body is what Wizards of the Coast has called a "Ribbon", i.e. a neat ability with mostly story, rather than mechanical, applications. Another ribbon ability is the rogue's Thieves' Cant, though that has more obvious benefits to the campaign at large.

See the sidebar in the Waterborne Adventures UA article [here](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Waterborne_v3.pdf) for a full explanation.

I can't think of many things that interact mechanically with timeless body. It wouldn't be unreasonable to rule that it also reduces aging from various mechanical effects, like Wild Magic Surges or potions of longevity, but aside from those edge cases, which are arguably subject to ruling anyway, the ability's mostly for fluff.

In story, I can see it causing very old archdruids running around the setting.

Comment: Interesting. Note that in D&D 3.5, aging would give -6 Str/Dex/Con and +3 Int/Wis/Cha, so getting Timeless Body before starting aging and then going up to Venerable was a way to get +3 Int/Wis/Cha "for free".